# Hiding WordPress Site & Image URLs

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

How do I hide the URLs for my WordPress images?

The reason why I want to hide them is because during the installation of WordPress 4.0 using WAMPServer, I followed several recommendations to help make WP more secure. One of these recommendations was to set a different Site Address and WP address (Settings -> General). For example:

> WordPress Address (URL): hxxp://samoca.org/here
>   Site Address (URL): hxxp://samoca.org/

This works fine to disguise the folder containing my WP site. However, when I hover over an image on the site, it displays the true URL. For example:

> hxxp://samoca.org/here/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/myimage.jpg

I tried setting the *Attachment Display Settings* to none but I'm still able to retrieve the URL by right-clicking on the image.

Being able to display the true image URL defeats the purpose of having different WordPress Address & Site Address.  Any suggestions as to how to hide image URLs will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Same problem, and general confusion about why there are articles that suggest this tactic without mentioning the very easy workaround for a hacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a plugin to do this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-real-download-path/

Comment: I tried this plugin and noticed it does not display the image URL when the mouse is hovered over the image. However, if I right click on the image and select "copy image location", I'm still able to get the URL. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would play around with file permissions.  The only way I think you might be able to do this is by removing all public permissions from the image directory and only allowing PHP to access that file.  As long as your image directory has a blank index.html file in each folder you should not have any issues with the absolute path.  If you are really concerned with absolute security then I would suggest getting one of the plugins that will completely hide you WP Path.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose to hide that you're using Wordpress by hiding the path, you may try this one http://benword.com/how-to-hide-that-youre-using-wordpress/